# CSS fade transition (no jQuery)

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a visual transition between content changes in a toy SPA I'm writing. To that end, I define a simple class for animating the opacity of an element.

```
.fade {
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
}
```

In my render function, I now change the opacity of my `outlet` div after content changes like so:

```
function render(content) {
  var outlet = document.getElementById("outlet");  

  outlet.classList.remove("fade");
  outlet.style.opacity = 0;

  outlet.innerHTML = content;
  outlet.classList.add("fade");
  outlet.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Unfortunately, the animation never fires. When I delay changing the opacity to 1 via `setTimeout` for 10ms, say, it works *sometimes* if I don't change the content again while the animation is still running, indicating a timing issue/race condition.

I used a similar approach in the past to fade out messages, but there I intentionally delayed changing the opacity by a few seconds so users could read the message before it starts fading out.

Comment: if you are doing the animation with css, then don't change the opacity with js - just toggle the class

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, I hope this will solve the issue**

```css
.fade{
       animation-name: example;
       animation-duration: 4s;}
       @keyframes example {
       from {opacity:1}
       to {opacity:0;}
       }
  div{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#000;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fade"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS animation `fadeIn`

```css
li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -75px;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: -150px;
  z-index: 30;
  -webkit-animation: fade-in-slogan 4s .2s ease-in forwards;
     -moz-animation: fade-in-slogan 4s .2s ease-in forwards;
          animation: fade-in-slogan 4s .2s ease-in forwards;
}

.menu {
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;  
  margin-left: -300px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fade-in-menu 3s 4s ease-out forwards;
     -moz-animation: fade-in-menu 3s 4s ease-out forwards;
          animation: fade-in-menu 3s 4s ease-out forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-slogan {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  30%  { opacity: 1; }
  50%  { opacity: 1; }
  70%  { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in-menu {
  0%   { display: block; opacity: 0;  }
  30% { display: block; opacity: .3; }
  60% { display: block; opacity: .6; }
  80% { display: block; opacity: .8; }
  100% { display: block; opacity: 1; } 
}
```

```html
<ul class"main">
  <li class="logo"></li>
  <li class="menu"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it now inspired by [Muhammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59173901/9721109). I defined the `fade` class as follows:

```css
.fade {
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 1.25s;
  @keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the `render` function, I do

```
function render(content) {
  outlet.classList.remove("fade");
  outlet.innerHTML = "";
  setTimeout(() => {
    outlet.classList.add("fade");
    outlet.appendChild(content);
  }, 100);
}
```

Even though this adds an additional delay before the new content actually starts to fade in, it seems the most elegant and concise solution to me.